# How to use functions from Statistics and Machine Learning Toolbox of MATLAB in Octave in Ubuntu?

Tags: 22.04, octave

I need to run a (MATLAB) code which has the `normrnd` function, available in the Statistics and Machine Learning Toolbox of MATLAB. However, I want to use GNU Octave instead of MATLAB.

How do I run this code in Octave in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `statistics` package in Octave provides this function, and it tries to be mostly compatible with Statistics and Machine Learning Toolbox in MATLAB.

To install it, open Octave, and enter the command

```
pkg install statistics
```

To get the latest (unreleased) version with many new features,

```
pkg install "https://github.com/gnu-octave/statistics/archive/refs/heads/main.zip"
```

(Note: This command downloads the source, compiles, and installs it. It may take several minutes for it to complete. Don't lose patience and terminate the process)

---

Now you can run `pkg load statistics` and run Statistics and Machine Learning Toolbox functions like `normrnd`.